# Question About Kanji , 發, and 発

Tags: kanji, questions, word-requests, chinese

I have a question regarding this kanji: . Is it the same kanji with this 發 or 発?

> The kanji of the Green dragon tiles in Japan is usually  which is slightly different from 發 since it includes the kanji 矢 instead of 殳." ([Wikipedia - Japanese Mahjong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_Mahjong)).

On last summer Japan trip, I was looking for some calligraphy stuffs near Asakusa, then I asked the Obasan to make me 發 word. She asked me whether that is 発 "Hatsu" because she said she doesn't know that word (發) exists in Japanese. But she did not tell me this kanji: .

I know 發 word from Chinese 發財 and HK Mahjong.

I hope native/Japanese expert could explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

發 is a old character form.
発 is a new character form.
Japanese don't use 發 in a normal life.
I didn't know what the word ether.
But, Japanese Mahjong players should know 發.

http://kanji.jitenon.jp/sp/kanjil/5749.html

I still can't write English well.
I would be glad if I could help you even just a little.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After saw your answer, then I searched about it and found the term _Shinjitai_. I did not know Japanese has this, I only know there are simplified and traditional for Chinese. 
I am going to learn more about Japanese now.

Comment: These characters are the same: Traditional, Japanese-variant (Shin-jitai) and Simplified: 發・発・发 - But you may see this word in Japanese: 撥水 where the right-side of the first kanji has not been officially simplified.